# What locks are involved with Select INTO statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, select-into

In MySQL, just like there is locking involved with SELECT combined with INSERT or CREATE, does the same hold true for SELECT column INTO @variable statement?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming InnoDB and no explicit locking (`FOR UPDATE`, etc.) - no locks are involved. 
It's just a normal select, except that the result goes in to some variables.

The locking in the other cases is because of the INSERT/UPDATE, not the select itself (and it doesn't lock the tables in the select).

`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ...` doesn't lock anything afaik.

Comment: From the fine manual :)

"CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ... performs the SELECT with shared next-key locks or as a consistent read, as for INSERT ... SELECT."

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: Well... yes, apparently it does, for REPEATABLE READ and SERIALIZABLE. No locks for READ COMMITTED though :)